# How data looping in under foreach laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

how I can foreach data under foreach data came from database like this bellow.

```
{"details":"Up to 5 Groups / Month","details":"Up to 30 CSV File Importing / 
Month","details":"Up to 5 SMTP Config","details":"Up to 5 Email Template Can Make and 
Edit","details":"Up to 30 Writer Call / Month","details":"24x7 Support"}
```

This array data stored on database in $TABALE_1 (model) on FSLS (row) so I foreach $TABLE_1 like this.

```
@foreach ($TABLE_1 as $lists)
Name: {{$lists->name}}

 @foreach($lists->FSLS as $fLists)
   Name_2: {{$fLists['details']}}
 @endforeach

@endforeach
```

I don't How I do it, I just shear how I try, please help if you understand.

Answer (score 0):

you get the object you need an array ( example object {} to array [] )

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: I try it, but not working

Comment: ["details":"Up to 5 Groups / Month","details":"Up to 30 CSV File Importing / 
Month","details":"Up to 5 SMTP Config","details":"Up to 5 Email Template Can Make and 
Edit","details":"Up to 30 Writer Call / Month","details":"24x7 Support"]

Comment: it's solved I use like this json_decode($TABALE_1 ) under 2nd foreach then it's solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just typecast it, like this.

```
@foreach ($TABLE_1 as $lists)
Name: {{$lists->name}}

 @foreach($lists->FSLS as $fLists)
   Name_2: {{ (array)$fLists['details'] }}
 @endforeach

@endforeach
```